# GroovyScriptEngine and groovy classes from different package

Tags: groovy

Was planning to use Groovy inside OSGi, loading scripts from different bundles, but thought I'd start easy with some Groovy files and a simple jUnit test.. turns out that was a good idea. I immediately ran into problems with Groovy classes in different packages.

I've created a GroovyScriptEngine with a custom ResourceConnector, all it does is print the requested file and then try to load it from the classpath (resource dir). With error handling removed:

```
public URLConnection getResourceConnection(String arg0) throws ResourceException {
    System.err.println("Wanted: " + arg0);
    return getClass().getResource("/" + arg0).openConnection();
}
```

So, in my resources (resources because I'll be loading them from OSGi bundles or filesystem later) dir I have the following directory structure:

```
com\test\groovy\SubPackageWithNoImport.groovy
com\test\groovy\SubPackageWithImport.groovy
com\test\groovy\SubPackageWithStaticImport.groovy
com\test\groovy\sub\IsolatedSub.groovy
```

The SubPackageWith* files attempts to call a method on the "IsolatedSub" class.

IsolatedSub.groovy:

```
package com.test.groovy.sub;

public class IsolatedSub
{
    public int dummy() {
        return 1337;
    }
    public static int dummy2() {
        return 1338;
    }
}
```

SubPackageWithNoImport.groovy:

```
package com.test.groovy;

public class SubPackageNoImport {
    public int dummy() {
        IsolatedSub s = new IsolatedSub();
        return s.dummy();
    }
}
```

SubPackageWithImport.groovy:

```
package com.test.groovy;

import com.test.groovy.sub.IsolatedSub;
public class SubPackageWithImport {
    public int dummy() {
        IsolatedSub s = new IsolatedSub();
        return s.dummy();
    }
}
```

SubPackageWithStaticImport.groovy:

```
package com.test.groovy;

import static com.test.groovy.sub.IsolatedSub.dummy2;
public class SubPackageWithImportStatic {
    public int dummy() {
        return dummy2();
    }
}
```

Code I use to execute is this (in a jUnit test):

```
// "this" implements ResourceConnector as shown above
GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine(this, getClass().getClassLoader());

Class<?> cl = engine.loadScriptByName("com/test/groovy/SubPackageNoImport.groovy");
GroovyObject o = (GroovyObject)cl.newInstance();
Object rv = o.invokeMethod("dummy", null);
```

I can load individual classes with no dependencies just fine, can also have dependencies in the same directory, but as soon as I go to a sub- or super-package, things break.

For SubPackageWithNoImport (attempts to use IsolatedSub without importing it), it attempts to load the following from the ResourceConnector:

```
Wanted: com/test/groovy/SubPackageNoImport.groovy
Wanted: com/test/groovy/IsolatedSub.groovy
```

Yeah, makes sense... I didn't specify a package, so it should be the same

Now it starts to get weird, SubPackageWithImport:

```
Wanted: com/test/groovy/SubPackageWithImport.groovy
Wanted: java/lang/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
```

This looks .. off to me, inner class to "com" in java.lang???

For SubPackageWithStaticImport:

```
Wanted: com/test/groovy/SubPackageWithImportStatic.groovy
Wanted: com/test/groovy/com/test/groovy/sub/IsolatedSub.groovy
```

Closer, but still wrong.

So, that was the background... my questions are:
What am I doing wrong?
How is GroovyScriptEngine supposed to work with groovy classes that have different package names?

Extra question: I've tried to add a custom protocol, ie, "test://filegoeshere", it gets sent to the resource connector for the first class, but not for its dependencies - is this as it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm... after modifying the resource connector and having it throw an exception if the class that is to be loaded isn't part of "my code", these are the files it asks for:

```
Wanted: com/test/groovy/SubPackageWithImport.groovy
Wanted: java/lang/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: java/io/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: java/net/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: java/util/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: groovy/lang/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: groovy/util/com$test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: com/test$groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: com/test/groovy$sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: com/test/groovy/sub$IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: com/test/groovy/sub/IsolatedSub.groovy
Wanted: com\test\groovy\SubPackageWithImportBeanInfo.groovy
Wanted: com\test\groovy\SubPackageWithImportCustomizer.groovy
Wanted: com\test\groovy\sub\IsolatedSubBeanInfo.groovy
Wanted: com\test\groovy\sub\IsolatedSubCustomizer.groovy
```

Code works fine now, but I'm not sure this is the correct approach.
Checking if the "wanted file" starts with some version of "com.test.groovy" is a bit messed... happily accepting alternate solutions :)